# Rename all FKs and IDXs names

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am working on MySql Workbench and everytime I rename a table/column, the existing FKs and IDXs names don't change. I ended up with a model with all the FK/IDX names messed up. Is there any way to regenerate all names according to the new tables and columns names or do I have to change them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Straight on the model i haven't found any regeneration of FKs etc. A workaround is the following, but you have to forward engineer your model first in order to have a schema:

Use and customize the following statement:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, COLUMN_NAME,
CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `your_schema`.`',TABLE_NAME,'` DROP INDEX `',INDEX_NAME,'`, ADD INDEX `fk_',TABLE_NAME,'_',COLUMN_NAME,'_idx` (`',COLUMN_NAME,'` ASC);') as statement
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema';
```

Customize the WHERE above in order to exclude e.g. `PRIMARY` indexes or anything else.
You can also set the prefix and suffix of index names that is appropriate for you in the `CONCAT` expression.

The first 3 columns in the above SELECT will be used in order to create the fourth expression. You can use the result of the fourth expression to batch-create the needed statements.

It may not seems the fastest solution but, once you add your final statement to your snippets, the next time will be quick and easy to regenerate your schema indexes.